# Removing headers from pages other than title page

Tags: header-footer, titles, overleaf

I have the following code (template taken from Overleaf.com for Projects/Lab Projects)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\input{pagesettings}

% If using on writelatex, you also need to set the document title in the document settings 
%(the cog button) because  they use the \title contents not the actual document title 

\def\papertitle{ ENTER }
\def\attribution{ENTER} 


\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\newcommand{\cut}[1]{}
\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\\ \hspace*{\fill}\framebox {#1} }

%\renewcommand{\ans}[1]{} 
%Uncomment the line above to remove answers.

\title{\papertitle}

 \date{\today}

\begin{document}


 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyfoot{}
 \fancyhead{}
 \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
 \fancyfoot[C]{}
 \fancyhead[L]{\attribution}

 \fancyhead[R]{\raisebox{-0.8cm}{ \includegraphics[height=2cm]{ENTER}}}



 \maketitle

 \end{document}
```

Basically it produces me with a title page with some text in the corner and a logo on the right hand side.  I am wondering is there a way to only have this text and logo on the first page? Or to at least replace the logo on subsequent pages with some text? I took this code from Overleaf.com so I do not completely understand all of its functionality.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template you're using is this one: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sps-computing-template/gsxvykcjvpyn.

First of all, you have to open the file `pagesettings.tex` (click on the button "PROJECT" on Overleaf to show that file) and comment the line

```
\renewcommand{\thispagestyle}[1]{}
```

After that, in `main.tex`, delete the line

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

and add

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

just after

```
\maketitle
```

and you're done.

This is the output from Overleaf:

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks! I played about with it some more and by putting \fancyhead[R]{} within the \newpage commands and in subsequent sections this also fixes it.

Comment: @CAF You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer, since it lead you to the solution you wanted (if you want).