# How to remove header from page that includes title page and table of contents in memoir document?

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm trying out the memoir class. My document so far:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\chapterstyle{culver}

\title{My Title}
\author{My Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Alpha}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Beta}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Gamma}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

I have a problem right now in that if I use the "culver" chapter style, the first page that includes the title page and table of contents ends up having the header. How do I get rid of this so that the title page doesn't include a header?

Comment: Does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256317/removing-headers-from-pages-other-than-title-page

Answer (score 1):

`\thispagestyle{plain}` is your friend here. Where it should go depends on the amount of the first chapter's text on the first page. Following your MWE this works:

```
...
\chapter{Alpha}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Beta}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-2]
...
```

However, when the first chapter's text spills over to the following page use:

```
\chapter{Alpha}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Beta}
\lipsum[1-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `cluver` chapter style sets the `chapter` *page style* to `headings`, it would be enough to use

```
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}
```

which is the standard in most cases.